# Working with Kafka and Schema Registry containers together in dotnet TestContainers

Tags: .net, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, testcontainers

I can't use the Kafka container along with the schema registry container in TestContainers. Here are my settings:

```
    private readonly KafkaContainer _kafkaContainer = new KafkaBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.1")
        .WithHostname("broker")
        .WithName("broker")
        .WithNetworkAliases("broker")
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .WithPortBinding(9092, 9092)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(9092))
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092" }
            }))
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .Build();
    
    private readonly IContainer _schemaRegistryContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.1")
        .WithHostname("schema-registry")
        .WithName("schema-registry")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "broker:29092" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081" }
            }))
        .WithPortBinding(8081, 8081)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(8081))
        .WithNetwork(NetworkName)
        .Build();
```

What I see on logs of schema registry container:

```
2023-12-21 13:27:21 [2023-12-21 12:27:21,315] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (broker/172.27.0.2:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:22 [2023-12-21 12:27:22,364] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:22 [2023-12-21 12:27:22,364] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (broker/172.27.0.2:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:23 [2023-12-21 12:27:23,604] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:23 [2023-12-21 12:27:23,604] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (broker/172.27.0.2:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:24 [2023-12-21 12:27:24,741] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:24 [2023-12-21 12:27:24,742] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (broker/172.27.0.2:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
2023-12-21 13:27:25 [2023-12-21 12:27:25,772] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

What should I change to make them work together successfully?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try connecting to `broker:9092` in you schema registry? Also checkout out [this](https://github.com/shelajev/testcontainers-workshop-snapshot/blob/spring-boot-3.1-local-dev-env-example/src/test/java/com/example/demo/ContainerConfig.java#L74) Java example.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't help, when I change it to `{ "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "broker:9092" }`, I get this time: 
`2023-12-21 15:46:07 [2023-12-21 14:46:07,636] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

Comment: Ok, I will ask my colleague about it, he is our Kafka expert for Testcontainers in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not 100% understand why it has to be this, and why the other config doesn't work. But this is the setup that starts both containers successfully:

```
    private readonly static INetwork network = new NetworkBuilder()
        .WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"))
        .Build();
  
    private static readonly KafkaContainer _kafkaContainer = new KafkaBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.1")
        .WithNetworkAliases("kafka")
        .WithNetwork(network)
        .WithEnvironment(new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL", "http://schemaregistry:8085"}
        }))
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .Build();
    
    private static readonly IContainer _schemaRegistryContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.1")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .WithEnvironment(
            new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9093" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL", "PLAINTEXT"},
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8085" },
                { "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schemaregistry" }
            }))
        .WithPortBinding(8085, true)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilMessageIsLogged("Server started, listening for requests"))
        .WithNetwork(network)
        .WithNetworkAliases("schemaregistry")
        .DependsOn(_kafkaContainer)
        .Build();
```

Note that the `KafkaBuilder` already exposes the ports, and does the configuration for waiting and other details like that. So we only add the network info and tell it to expect a schema registry.

The schema registry container, for which we don't have a module (but maybe actually should, or like have an extension of the Kafka module to add the Schema Registry container to the setup), needs more config.

I also changed the ports to mirror my example in Java that was shared in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine. I have a followup question: when the container is up, for some reason I can not access to `http://schemaregistry:8085` or `http://localhost:8085` or `http://127.0.0.1:8085`. Do you have any idea why? I'm looking to create schemas for my topics programmatically

Comment: The exposed ports `.WithExposedPort(8085)` map to random high value port on the host to avoid conflicts (like 2 kafka brokers for a cluster or running tests in parallel). You can access it with `_schemaRegistryContainer.Hostname + ":" + _schemaRegistryContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(8085)`. Here `KafkaBuilder` uses this approach to set ADVERTISED_LISTENERS so it has the address available from the outside: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/main/src/Testcontainers.Kafka/KafkaBuilder.cs#L82

Comment: `schemaregistry:8085` that would be available in the Docker network, cause we set the alias to `schemaregistry` and inside the ports are available directly. 

But for the access from the host, it really is preferred to have the dynamic mappings. Since you normally consume the containers programmatically, it doesn't complicate things (beyond the initial surprise maybe)

Comment: I feel like I'm moving around a bug. When I call `_schemaRegistryContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(8085)`, I get a NullReferenceException and when I inspect the container I see the ports section as below: `"Ports": { "8081/tcp": null, "8085/tcp": null },`
Is that normal I see null values?

Comment: Please, add .WithPortBinding(8085, true) instead of .WithExposedPort(8085)

Comment: Thanks @EddúMeléndez, that did the trick. Happy Christmas to all that celebrates, you saved my day.

Comment: Thank you @EddúMeléndez! Sorry, @xkcd, that's my Java background sticking out, in the testcontainers-java API, withExposedPorts behaves differently. I edited the answer to have WithPortBinding for precision!

Comment: Why modify the default ports? I don't think kafka container needs schema registry address, that's only a feature of `cp-server` image

Comment: I'm not sure. Does it work for you without setting the `KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL`? I think my initial setup was inspired by https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry-workshop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml that's where 8085 comes from. I'm not a Kafka or Schema registry expert, just know how to Testcontainers things.